# I want to convert a 3 field datatable into a Dictionary<string, tuple<int,string>>

Tags: c#, linq

```
     static Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, string>> GetDict(DataTable dt)
    {
        return dt.AsEnumerable()
          .ToDictionary<DataRow, string, Tuple<int,string>>(row => row.Field<string>(0)
            ,    new { Tuple < int, string >( row.Field<int>(1),  row.Field<string>(2)) });
    }
```

Field 0 is  a unique key. .net 4.5

Comment: This doesn't work. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
        static Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, string>> GetDict(DataTable dt)
    {
        return dt.AsEnumerable()
          .ToDictionary<DataRow, string, Tuple<int, string>>(
            row => row.Field<string>(0), row => new Tuple<int, string>
                (row.Field<int>(1), row.Field<string>(2)) );
    }
```

Comment: Glad you figured out what you're trying to do, but I have to be honest: this is some really ugly code. I would hate to have to maintain this. I despise the Tuple<> class because of code like this.